# Runtime creation of LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects, mongodb-.net-driver

Say I have this expression:

```
int setsize = 20;
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = x => x.Seed % setsize == 1
                                          || x.Seed % setsize == 4;
```

This basically 'partitions' a set of elements into 20 partitions and retrieves from each set each first and fourth element.

This expression is passed to [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which it's [driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/mongocsharpdriver/) is perfectly capable of translating into a MongoDB "query". The predicate can, however, also be used on a list of objects (LINQ2Objects) etc. I want this expression to be reusable ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). However, I want to be able to pass in an [`IEnumerable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) to specify which items to retrieve (so 1 and 4 aren't "hardcoded" into it):

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> GetPredicate(IEnumerable<int> items) {
    //Build expression here and return it
}
```

With [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) using this code:

```
int setsize = 20;
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = x => x.Seed % setsize == 1 || x.Seed % setsize == 4;
predicate.Dump();

} 

class Foo
{
    public int Seed { get; set; }
```

I can examine the expression:

[image: Expression]

Now, I want to be able to build an exact reproduction of this expression but with a variable amount of integers to pass (so instead of 1 and 4 I could pass, for example, `[1, 5, 9, 11]` or `[8]` or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 16]`).

I have tried using [BinaryExpressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx) etc. but haven't been able to construct this message correctly. The main issue is that most of my [attempt](http://pastebin.com/qDwXGGit)s will fail when passing the predicate to MongoDB. **The "hardcoded" version works fine** but somehow all my attempts to pass my dynamic expressions fail to be translated into a MongoDB query by the C# driver:

```
{
    "$or" : [{
        "Seed" : { "$mod" : [20, 1] }
    }, {
        "Seed" : { "$mod" : [20, 4] }
    }]
}
```

Basically, I want to dynamically build the expression at runtime in such a way that it exactly replicates what the compiler generates for the 'hardcoded' version.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

[As requested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583565/runtime-creation-of-linq-expression#comment23832188_16583565) (and [posted on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qDwXGGit)), one of my tries below. I'm posting it in the question for furure reference should pastebin take it down or stop their serivce or...

```
using MongoRepository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoRepository<Foo> repo = new MongoRepository<Foo>();
        var reporesult = repo.All().Where(IsInSet(new[] { 1, 4 }, 20)).ToArray();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> IsInSet(IEnumerable<int> seeds, int setsize)
    {
        if (seeds == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");

        if (!seeds.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("No sets specified");

        return seeds.Select<int, Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>>(seed => x => x.Seed % setsize == seed).JoinByOr();
    }
}

public class Foo : Entity
{
    public int Seed { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> JoinByOr<T>(this IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> filters)
    {
        var firstFilter = filters.First();
        var body = firstFilter.Body;
        var param = firstFilter.Parameters.ToArray();
        foreach (var nextFilter in filters.Skip(1))
        {
            var nextBody = Expression.Invoke(nextFilter, param);
            body = Expression.Or(body, nextBody);
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    }
}
```

This results in: `Unsupported where clause: <InvocationExpression>`.

Comment: Please show some - or at least one - of your tries.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/qDwXGGit. This results in: `Unsupported where clause: <InvocationExpression>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> GetExpression<T>(
    int setSize, int[] elements,
    Expression<Func<Foo, T>> property)
{
    var seedProperty = GetPropertyInfo(property);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo));
    Expression body = null;

    foreach(var element in elements)
    {
        var condition = GetCondition(parameter, seedProperty, setSize, element);
        if(body == null)
            body = condition;
        else
            body = Expression.OrElse(body, condition);
    }

    if(body == null)
        body = Expression.Constant(false);        

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(body, parameter);    
}

public Expression GetCondition(
    ParameterExpression parameter, PropertyInfo seedProperty,
    int setSize, int element)
{
    return Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Modulo(Expression.Property(parameter, seedProperty),
                          Expression.Constant(setSize)),
        Expression.Constant(element));
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(LambdaExpression propertyExpression)
{
    if (propertyExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");

    var body = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                "'propertyExpression' should be a member expression, "
                + "but it is a {0}", propertyExpression.Body.GetType()));
    }

    var propertyInfo = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                "The member used in the expression should be a property, "
                + "but it is a {0}", body.Member.GetType()));
    }

    return propertyInfo;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
GetExpression(setSize, elements, x => x.Seed);
```

---

If you want it to be generic in `Foo` also, you need change it like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetExpression<TEntity, TProperty>(
    int setSize, int[] elements,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property)
{
    var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(property);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    Expression body = null;

    foreach(var element in elements)
    {
        var condition = GetCondition(parameter, propertyInfo , setSize, element);
        if(body == null)
            body = condition;
        else
            body = Expression.OrElse(body, condition);
    }

    if(body == null)
        body = Expression.Constant(false);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter);    
}
```

Now, the call would look like this:

```
GetExpression(setSize, elements, (Foo x) => x.Seed);
```

In this scenario it is important to specify the type of `x` explicitly, otherwise type-inference won't work and you would have to specify both `Foo` and the type of the property as generic arguments to `GetExpression`.

Comment: HOLY CRAP! That works! Thanks! Now, not to be an ass or something, is there any way I can avoid using the `"Seed"` string so that when refactoring etc. this will also be picked up? More specifically: couldn't I "just" pass a "lamba" or something to make this a bit more "generic"? Either way: this answer is very much appreciated!

Comment: You, sir, are pure epic win! Thanks a lot!