# MongoDB with C# - query with dynamically generated predicate

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am having trouble querying a MongoDB database using a predicate which is dynamically generated.

The document structue i am trying to query on is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 3121 , 
    "Active" : true , 
    "CategoryId" : 1 , 
    "Crci" : "IH" , 
    "CultureId" :  null  , 
    "DateUpdated" : { 
            "$date" : 1381916923120
    } , 
    "Description" : "National Careers Service: Actuary" , 
    "Keywords" : "" , 
    "MaxLevel" :  null  , 
    "MinLevel" :  null  , 
    "PhoneNumber" : "                    " , 
    "Priority" : 1 , 
    "Title" : "National Careers Service: Actuary" , 
    "WebUrl" : "https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/advice/planning/jobprofiles/Pages/actuary.aspx" , 
    "CareerCultureExternalResources" : [ 
        { 
                "CareerId" : 5 , 
                "CultureId" : 1 , 
                "DisplayOrder" : 1 , 
                "ExternalResourceId" : 3121 , 
                "Vgs" :  null 
        }
    ] , 
    "SubjectExternalResources" : [ ] , 
    "LifestyleCategories" :  null
}
```

And I am trying to query using at predicate which is generated a runtime E.g.:

```
Expression<Func<ExternalResourceView, bool>> predicate = predicateBuilder.True<ExternalResourceView>();
if (request.CultureId != null && request.CareerId != null) {
    predicate = predicate.And(er => er.CareerCultureExternalResources.Any(ccer => ccer.CareerId == request.CareerId.Value && ccer.CultureId == request.CultureId.Value));
} 
else if (request.SubjectAreaId != null && request.SubjectLevel != null && request.CultureId != null)
{
    predicate = predicate.And(er => er.SubjectExternalResources.Any(ser => ser.SubjectAreaId == request.CareerId && ser.CultureId == request.CultureId));
}
IEnumerable<ExternalResourceView> matchingExternalResources = _externalResourceLibrary.AsQueryable().Where(predicate)
```

When I try and execute the query I get the error: "`Unsupported where clause: <InvocationExpression>`."

I am unable to find if the Linq to Mongo is able to generate a query from such an expression or not (I think it should).

So am I just trying to do something that the C# Mongo driver doesn't support or am I not generating the predicate right? I have seen from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583565/runtime-creation-of-linq-expression) that what I'm trying to do should be possible (in theory at least).

I am using the official 10gen driver ver 1.8.3

Comment: you can try .Tolist() irrespective of .AsQueryable()

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I completely forgot about AsExpandable()! And it did solve the problem. If you add this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure it's a solution for mongodb, but could you try to use `AsExpandable()` coming from linqkit (made by the same guy as PredicateBuilder).

LinqKit (and more info about `AsExpandable()` and relation with `PredicateBuilder`) can be found [here](http://albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: I can confirm it works for MongoDb. If you have a predicate in the form `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate;` Then you can query a mongo collection in C# by `collection.AsQueryable<Foo>().AsExpandable().Where(predicate);`

Comment: yes Expand does the trick for AndAlso expressions https://github.com/vip32/Naos/blob/f768336d666f3c11edf7ed2c051c0702ad0ff596/src/Infrastructure.MongoDb/Repositories/Extensions/WhereExpression.cs#L19

Answer (score 1):

Use the MongoDB Query builder instead of translating the predicate twice:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
List<IMongoQuery> queries = new List<IMongoQuery>();
if (request.CultureId != null && request.CareerId != null) {
  queries.Add(
    Query<Person>.ElemMatch<IDependent>(p => p.Dependents,
      q => Query.And(
        q.EQ(x => x.CareerId, request.CareerId),
        q.EQ(x => x.CultureId, request.CultureId))));
}
// ... etc
// Final Query: 
var query = Query.And(queries);
```

I changed the query to use an [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), because I have the feeling you want to match both `careerId` and `cultureId` on the same array element. If that assumption is wrong, adjust the query accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, you're right that we are doing extra work essentially translating the predicate twice - but we want to stick with linq rather than tying our querying to mongo in case we wish to switch in the future