# MongoDB C# .NET Driver ASP.NET Core Unsupported Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am having trouble making my filters work with MongoDB .NET Driver, I get this error:

`Unsupported filter: Invoke(value(System.Func2 [Role,System.Boolean]), {document}{Model}).`

When trying to run this code:

```
public virtual async Task<PartitionedModel<T>> GetByAsync(Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    Expression<Func<PartitionedModel<T>, bool>> filt = (i) => filter(i.Model);
    PartitionedModel<T> item = (await collection.FindAsync(filt)).FirstOrDefault();
    return item;
}
```

and the class **PartitionedModel** look like this:

```
public class PartitionedModel<T> where T : IModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public PartitionOffset PartitionOffset { get; set; }
    public T Model { get; set; }
}
```

I did a refacto of my code working from having collections handling **IModel** directly to working with **PartitionedModel** which is a holding class for my **IModel**, the **GetByAsync** function worked correctly before I subclassed **IModel**

I found little to no informations about this problem except this:
[Dynamic Linq Predicate throws "Unsupported Filter" error with C# MongoDB Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056386/dynamic-linq-predicate-throws-unsupported-filter-error-with-c-sharp-mongodb-dr)

But it seems like my version of the MongoDB C# Driver doesnt accept **Func<>** in parameter as filter, I can only pass **Builder<>** or **Expression<>** as a filter into the Find functions

Can someone enlighten me a bit about this error ?

**EDIT:**

I tried to run this code by replacing the `FindAsync(filt)` with `FindAsync(_ => true)` and it actually works

Also, here is the code that is used to retrieve the collection

```
protected readonly IMongoCollection<PartitionedModel<T>> collection;

public GenericRepository(IMongoDatabase dbContext, string collectionName)
{
    collection = dbContext.GetCollection<PartitionedModel<T>>(collectionName);
}
```

and the version of my driver seems to be **2.7.0**
[image: driver version]

**EDIT 2:**
I've made my query works using this:

`PartitionedModel<T> item = collection.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(filt);`

But i'm not sure what is the implication of using a non-async version, can anyone tell me if this is wrong or if this will be a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like current implementation of c# mongo driver is not supported delegate-based filters.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/da0cff54c67208d979b030abb160f958d3276925/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs#L76

The switch doesn't contain a ExpressionType.Invoke (the type of expression in delegate-based filter) case.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo doesn't work with invocation filters.  You can pass that invocation filter to LINQKit's expression expander and it will replace it with a predicate that the Mongo driver can then fully understand.

[Magic is here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/LinqKit.Core/Extensions.cs#L64)

[See it in action here](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/tests/LinqKit.Tests.Net452/DeepInvocationTests.cs#L52)

Comment: Do you have more explanation sources on usage? Can't get it working, I saw your answer on another post but still.

Comment: Given any Expression just invoke the .Expand() extension method provided by LINQKit before you send it to any of the Mongo functions.

The 2nd link takes both a selector expression from a sub document and chains together an and clause via predicate builder.  I feed that expanded expression into Mongo on every single query I run against my databases transactional documents.  I actually wrote that test for LINQKit when it blew up last summer.